# Is there any statistics regarding the usage of Spring MVC vs Struts 2 and other frameworks?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, spring-mvc, struts

I'm doing an analysis of request-based web application frameworks to determine which one would be the most suitable for a particular project, and I've been asked to include some solid evidence showing that our choice is widely used and supported compared to other frameworks.

Is there any statistics on the matter? Or even a list of major companies that use each one or something?

Comment: Have a look here: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-tools-and-technologies-landscape-2016/ (Which Web Frameworks do you use).

Historical data: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-tools-and-technologies-landscape-2016-trends/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its hard to say anything which framework best fit in your needs as only you can do the analysis based on your requirements and see which framework provides best nearest match as per your requirements.

Matt Raible has done a very deep level analysis based on some predefined matrix and you can get some idea about few frameworks

- [my_comparing_jvm_web_frameworks](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/my_comparing_jvm_web_frameworks)

In end i will suggest you don't go with what other saying as those can be there personal preferences and it's better to invest you time to find which is better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides other lot more features like security, dependency Injection, AOP and transactions. So you need to use spring anyway in your application.

So what I think is why you need a different framework like Struts just for a MVC frontend when Spring itself provides it.

Think about it. If you use struts you will add dependency on one more framework unnecessarily.

Comment: well what you said is too abstract.there are many applications out there using so many combination and yes Spring provides little of everything but that does not mean its the end of world :)

Comment: I'm actually in the same position (analyzing for a replacement for Struts in my organization). Spring definitely beats up Struts in all aspects in my opinion. Ease of use, less boilerplate, features rich, testability, support/community, you name it. It is really a no brainer these days, especially Spring 4.x which allows Java Config and annotation-driven configuration. It really makes it a powerful and smart framework to work with. Also, Struts is on a downward slope these days in terms of usage around the globe.

Answer (score 0):

Some info on their respective homepages

http://www.springsource.org/case-studies

https://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/projects-using-webwork-or-struts2.html